# UI - React how to add image in the same row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

[enter image description here][1]I used parent  tag and kept the 3 div tags, when I tried to add the image in the same line it's going to the next line. How can we keep all these 3 div in same row like below

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-2  gap-x-8 gap-y-4 pb-4">
<div> TCP </div>
<div> 12 </div>.
<div> <img src="images/deleteIcon" alt="Delete Icon"/> </div>
</div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgk77.png
```

Comment: 3 div but why you set `grid-cols-2`

Comment: I have changed it to cols-3, did not work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what these classes do but ...

If the container is `display: flex`, then set `flex-wrap: nowrap`

If the container is NOT `display: flex` then set `white-space: nowrap`